# ESP32 - Connect arduino nano with ESP32 with Serial

Tags: arduino, uart, esp32

I want to connect my arduino nano with my ESP-32 (in order to use it for wireless communications).

I got this ESP board (see pic).

Any idea how I can connect it? I can't find any documentation for the pin on this board.

[image: ESP-32 Board]

Comment: *"I can't find any documentation for the pin on this board"* -- My rule is never acquire hardware that does not have documentation.  Your board looks like a clone of a [LOLIN32 Lite](https://wiki.wemos.cc/products:lolin32:lolin32_lite).

Comment: what documentation? the labels on PCB are the pin numbers of the ESP32 to use in code.

Comment: *"Any idea how I can connect it?"* -- Use the USB connector.  The LOLIN32 Lite schematic indicates that the serial port of the ESP-32 is converted to a USB connection using a CH340C chip.  You'll need an appropriate USB driver on your host computer.

Comment: @sawdust I want to connect to another arduino actually. I can't use software serial to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check this,
 https://www.espressif.com/en/products/hardware/esp32/resources

You can directly use ESP32 to perform the same functions of arduino.

Comment: Thank you. But on this esp board I cannot find the tx and rx pins to read from the serial.. Any idea?

Comment: This may help you, https://www.google.com/amp/s/circuits4you.com/2018/12/31/esp32-hardware-serial2-example/amp/